# Prove $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{2n\cdot4^n} = \ln(2/5^{0.5})$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation

I proved that the following summation converges but how to prove that the it is equal to $\ln(2/5^{0.5})$

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{2n\cdot4^n}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: derive $\sum \frac{x^n}{2n}$ calculate the sum, and re-integrate for $x=-\frac 14$.

Comment: But here I have (-1)^n...

Comment: This is why $x$ is a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Use
$\ln(1+x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}
$
and put $x = \dfrac14$.

This gives
$\ln(1+\frac14)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{4^nn}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{4^n2n}
&=-\dfrac12 \ln(5/4)\\
&=-\ln(\sqrt{5/4})\\
&=-\ln(\sqrt{5}/2)\\
&=\ln(2/\sqrt{5})\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thanks but why I can't use that $$\log(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \dfrac{x^n}n$$

Comment: from that I get -log(1+1/4)/2 which is equal to the summation of (-1)^n/(2*n*4^n)